# How can I detect if the iPhone my app is on, is going to use a simple transparent effect instead of the blur effect?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

My app on iPhone 4 running iOS 7 uses a UITabBar with a custom `barTintColor`. As mentioned in Apple documentation : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UITabBar.html

> Tab bars are translucent by default on iOS 7. Additionally, there is a system blur applied to all tab bars. This allows your content to show through underneath the bar.

But this system blur is not visible on iPhone 4 and the `UITabBar` goes transparent on the device as shown below:

[image]

I *believe* that this might be happening because of the weaker GPU in iPhone 4 and thus it must be falling back to transparency instead of translucency. Reference : http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/09/new-lease-on-life-or-death-sentence-ios-7-on-the-iphone-4/

A simple solution to this can be to conditionally make the `UITabBar` `translucent` for iPhone 4. But instead of putting this dependancy on the device type, I want to know if I can somehow detect if the iOS is going to be falling back to transparency when GPU is weak? (Thus making the condition more appropriate)

Comment: I am afraid that there is no way to find whether translucence is supported or not as that is determined by the GPU at run time. The best approach would be to check for the device version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some quick and dirty categories that detects if the device supports blur. Hope it solves your problem

```
@interface UIToolbar (support)
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL supportsBlur;
@end

@implementation UIToolbar (support)
    -(BOOL) supportsBlur{
        return [self _supportsBlur:self];
    }


    -(BOOL)_supportsBlur:(UIView*) view{
        if ([view isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"_UIBackdropEffectView")]){
            return YES;
        }

        for (UIView* subview in view.subviews){
            if ([self _supportsBlur:subview]){
                return YES;
            }
        }
        return NO;
    }
@end

// Use this category to detect if the device supports blur
@interface UIDevice (support)
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL supportsBlur;
@end


@implementation UIDevice (support)
    -(BOOL) supportsBlur{
        static BOOL supportsBlur = NO;
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken = 0;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            UIToolbar* toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
            [toolBar layoutSubviews];
            supportsBlur = toolBar.supportsBlur;
        });
        return supportsBlur;
    }
@end
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? I believe a toolbar will have the `_UIBackdropView` as a subview even if the device doesn't support blurring.

Comment: Updated the code to provide a category that lets you ask the device if it supports bluring

Comment: For a toolbar the subviews on an iPhone 4 are _UIToolbarBackground, _UIBackdropView, UIView, UIImageVie. For an iPhone 5: _UIToolbarBackground, _UIBackdropView, _UIBackdropEffectView. _UIBackdropEffectView is what we are looking for

Comment: Worth to notice, would make sense to wrap `supportsBlur` in dispatch_once to avoid re-creating Toolbar on each invocation and simply use static variable for flag.

Comment: I would agree the current implementation is not thread safe, however supportsBlur is static so the toolBar variable will only be created once.

Comment: However in an effort to provide the very best code I added dispatch_once

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's no way to "benchmark" the GPU in order to know if it's too weak to show the translucent effect. Even if you'll find such a way it would be an overkill instead of just checking if the current device is iPhone 4. The thing is that you can't check for bounds or something similar because you'd still want to show the effect on iPhone 4S so you can't exclude anything that is not iPhone 5.
Usually I use this simple class to identify the user device.

```
#import "UIDeviceHardware.h"
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

@implementation UIDeviceHardware

- (NSString *) platform{
    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    char *machine = malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:machine];
    free(machine);
    return platform;
}

- (NSString *) platformString{
    NSString *platform = [self platform];
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"Verizon iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,3"])    return @"iPhone 5c (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,4"])    return @"iPhone 5c (Global)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,1"])    return @"iPhone 5s (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,2"])    return @"iPhone 5s (Global)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 2G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 4G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 5G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])      return @"iPad Mini (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad 3 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad 3 (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad 3 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"])      return @"iPad 4 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"])      return @"iPad 4 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"])      return @"iPad 4 (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"])      return @"iPad Air (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"])      return @"iPad Air (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,4"])      return @"iPad Mini Retina (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,5"])      return @"iPad Mini Retina (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return @"Simulator";
    return platform;
}

@end
```

Comment: That surely is one way to do it (as I mentioned in the question too) but I want the dependancy on the OS rather than the device. To clear it a bit, it makes more sense because my condition is not "Make views opaque if device is iPhone 4", but it is "Make views opaque if iOS is going to draw it transparent rather than translucent".
What I am anticipating is some macro that the OS sets in such conditions. I hope Apple internally too does something like that, else the whole system would become brittle.

Comment: Suggested code attribution : https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/ https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/blob/master/UIDevice-Hardware.m